# Calculating milliseconds from epoch

Tags: javascript, date, time

Given that I have: mm, dd, yy, hh:mm, am/pm, what is the recommended/easiest way to convert that data into milliseconds from epoch?

Answer (score 34):

Everytime I get an upvote on this answer, I'm reminded that my answer doesn't *actually answer* the question.

OP: If you can parse your string into the following format, you can use one of the other answers. `MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM:SS AM EDT` (It's important to specify the timezone; epoch is based on the meridian)

```js
let milliseconds = new Date("1/20/1982 5:00 PM EST").getTime()
console.log(milliseconds);
```

**Original Answer that some people have found useful:**
Another technique (which most browsers support, as well as NodeJS) that doesn't require having to instantiate a `Date` object

```
var nowEpoch = Date.now();
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 22):

```
new Date("some string").getTime()
```

Answer (score 3):

You can get the milliseconds from [epoch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_epoch) with `+new Date('date string')`.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/K5NVf/).

The [`+`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#.2B_%28Unary_Plus%29) operator implicitly calls [`valueOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/valueOf) which returns the same as [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

Answer (score 0):

```
var date;

if(pm)
    date = new Date(yy, mm, dd, hh+12, mm, 0, 0);
else
    date = new Date(yy, mm, dd, hh, mm, 0, 0);

var millis = date.getTime();
var seconds = millis/1000;
```

Comment: I think you want your `seconds` assignment to be divided by 1000 rather than multiplied?

Answer (score 0):

var myDate = new Date(Timestamp); // Your timezone! either timestamp ot date
var myEpoch = myDate.getTime()/1000.0;