# How to get time in milliseconds since the unix epoch in Javascript?

Tags: javascript

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you get a timestamp in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/221294/how-do-you-get-a-timestamp-in-javascript)
>   [Calculating milliseconds from epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011758/calculating-milliseconds-from-epoch)

How can I get the current `epoch` time in Javascript?  Basically the number of milliseconds since midnight, 1970-01-01.

Comment: Note that this question (and some duplicates) ask for milliseconds since epoch. While JavaScript gives you this, note that standard Unix epoch is usually expression in seconds (1/1000 the value you get from JS).

Comment: `new Date/1E3|0` - instantiate `Date`, coerce to number, divide by 1000 and floor.

Comment: @CamiloMartin You should write this an an answer.  It's the best.

Comment: @Justin Thanks! But note that, since I wrote that, IE8 has become the kind of browser that you may be ready to say "no" to. If you're ready to discard IE8 support, use this: `Date.now()` (easily shimmable otherwise).

Answer (score 682, accepted):

[Date.now()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) returns a unix timestamp in milliseconds.

```js
const now = Date.now(); // Unix timestamp in milliseconds
console.log( now );
```

Prior to ECMAScript5 (I.E. Internet Explorer 8 and older) you needed to construct a Date object, from which there are several ways to get a unix timestamp in milliseconds:

```js
console.log( +new Date );
console.log( (new Date).getTime() );
console.log( (new Date).valueOf() );
```

Comment: Been searching for this for a good half hour.. So much mis-information  surrounding this simple line..

Comment: For a perfect Unix timestamp without the milliseconds, do this: var milliseconds = Math.floor((new Date).getTime()/1000);

Comment: Does this account for leap seconds?

Comment: @RaySuelzer It gets the time according the the system clock of the machine its running on, so it depends entirely on that.

Comment: Should it be var milliseconds = (new Date()).getTime(); ? Notice the 2 parentheses after Date.

Comment: @grenoult That means the same thing in Javascript. You only need parenthesis when passing arguments to a constructor. `((new Date())`, `new Date()`, and `(new Date)` would all work in this case. Use whichever you find the most readable.

Comment: @GeekStocks thnx a lot!!!!

Comment: @RaySuelzer Unix time does not account for leap seconds. For more information read the wikipedia entry on Unix time.

Comment: var milliseconds = +new Date;

Comment: `Date.now()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now

Comment: Good answer!  Note: If you want the milliseconds at two different points in a program, you need to create the (new Date) object at each point, and you cannot use the same one.

Comment: For milliseconds use         return new Date() / 1;

Answer (score 87):

This will do the trick :-

```
new Date().valueOf()
```

Comment: Did you get the parenthesis wrong? Check out this (rejected) [edit suggestion](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/14668514) from MarkHu.

Comment: No, it's working; you can check [this great answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36597316/1229023) explaining the reasons. BTW, this expression can be simplified up to `+new Date` - for the same reasons.

Comment: This would bomb out in php where you would need to do `(new DateTime)->format('U')` but js is ok without the parens