# How can I display the Epoch time in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, time, epoch

As you might know, you can display the time in JavaScript by doing `Date()` But can you display the Linux Epoch time in JavaScript?

I would like to know because I have a time converter and It would be nice to show the **current** Epoch time.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get time in milliseconds since the unix epoch in javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9575790/how-to-get-time-in-milliseconds-since-the-unix-epoch-in-javascript)

Comment: Looking at the two answers below, can you clarify if you want the actual Epoch time, as in when the Epoch was, or do you want the time _since_ the Epoch?

Comment: I want the current Epoch time.

Comment: Thanks - I've deleted my answer then, so as to not confuse the issue.  And just so you know, the Epoch is a set time so you're not looking for the "current Epoch time".  You're looking for a unix time (timestamp) since the Epoch :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to use the `.getTime()` method of the `Date` object.

```
var d = new Date();
alert(d.getTime());
```

Epoch is also called `timestamp`.

Answer (score 1):

Simple and straightforward.

```
 var milliseconds = new Date().getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

Older browsers:

```
(new Date).getTime()
```

New way:

```
Date.now()
```

Returns in milliseconds, so `epoch / 1000 | 0` to get seconds.