# how do I convert date to milliseconds

Tags: javascript

I have a string the represents a time "2014-07-03T11:47:00"

I would like to covert this time to milliseconds and I think it should look something like the following.

```
var myTime = Date.parse("2014-07-03T11:47:00");

var myTimeMs = myTime.getTime();
```

Any suggestions about how to get the value in milliseconds on any browser?

Comment: [Hmmm...](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmilliseconds.asp).

Comment: @RobertHarvey I think the OP wants the timestamp; the count of milliseconds since the epoch.

Comment: [Hmmm....](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011758/calculating-milliseconds-from-epoch)

Comment: That date format (ISO 8601) is always going to be interpreted as a UTC time. Internet Explorer versions before IE9 cannot deal with that format.

Comment: @Pointy—always, except for… ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Date.parse returns the time in milliseconds

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/parse

Comment: But *Date.parse* is not generally consistent across browsers in use, so should not be relied upon to convert a string to a Date.

Comment: RobG, any suggestions on how to do it in a reliable way across browsers?