# Google apps script new Date() undefined

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a timestamp to make a filename unique, but the Date object doesn't seem to be working as described.

```
var today = new Date();
var result = ui.alert(today.now());
```

This returns 'undefined'

```
var today = new Date();
var result = ui.alert(today);
```

returns a long formatted date string: Wed Aug 23 2017 11:40:13 GMT-0700 (PDT)

how do I get the number of milliseconds since the epoch?  Isn't this what the now() method is supposed to give?

Thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Calculating milliseconds from epoch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9011758/calculating-milliseconds-from-epoch)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Date.parse` which parses a string representation of a date, and returns the number of milliseconds since January 1, 1970, 00:00:00 UTC.

```js
console.log(Date.parse('Wed Aug 23 2017 11:40:13 GMT-0700 (PDT)'));
```

Or as alternative (please note the + operator returns the numeric representation of the object):

```js
console.log(+new Date('Wed Aug 23 2017 11:40:13 GMT-0700 (PDT)'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of parsing the output string, have you tried simply casting the Date object to a number?

```
var result = ui.alert(+today);
```

Answer (score 0):

Date.now() is static. Use it on Date instead of the today instance.

If you want the milliseconds on a instance of date, use [getTime()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettime.asp) instead.

So:

```
var today = Date.now();
var result = ui.alert(today);
```

or

```
var today = new Date();
var result = ui.alert(today.getTime());
```

https://jsfiddle.net/k_24/qof04cvc/

Edit: it wouldn't make sense to use now() on something that was created in the past ;)